# Shopware 6 Plugin - SEO Friendly Pagination: , null is returned from app.request.get('properties')

Tags: shopware, shopware6, shopware6-api

I'm currently developing a Shopware 6 plugin called "SEO Friendly Pagination" that aims to make paginated URLs in product categories accessible to search engine crawlers. To achieve this, I have extended the pagination template to include invisible href elements for each page in the pagination. These href elements are generated with SEO-friendly URLs that reflect the current context of the page, including sorting order and filters.

The pagination template in my custom plugin pagination.html.twig looks like this:

```
{# Extend the 'pagination.html.twig' template from the storefront #}
{% sw_extends '@Storefront/storefront/component/pagination.html.twig' %}

{# Define the 'component_pagination' block #}
{% block component_pagination %}
    
    {# Access the 'TanmarSeoPagination' data from the context #}
    {% set TanmarSeoPaginationData = context.context.extensions.tanmarNgSeoPagination %}

    {# Check if TanmarSeoPagination is active #}
    {% if TanmarSeoPaginationData.active %}
        
        {# Check if active navigation ID is defined in page header #}
        {% if page.header.navigation.active.id is defined %}
            {% set currentNavigationId = page.header.navigation.active.id %} 
        {% endif %}
        
        {# Check if navigation ID is defined in search filters #}
        {% if searchResult.currentFilters.navigationId is defined %}
            {% set currentNavigationId = searchResult.currentFilters.navigationId %}
        {% endif %}
        
        {% for i in 1..totalPages %}
            {# Set up an empty SEO parameters object #}
        {% set seoParams = {} %}
        
        {# Check and set 'order' parameter from request #}
        {% set order = app.request.get('order') %}
        {% if order %}
            {% set seoParams = seoParams|merge({ order: order }) %}
        {% endif %}
        
        {# Calculate the next page number #}
        {% set pageNumber = currentPage + 1 %}
        {% if i != currentPage %}
            {% if pageNumber %}
            {% set seoParams = seoParams|merge({ p: i }) %}
        {% endif %}
   
        {# Check and set 'properties' parameter from request #}
        {% set properties = app.request.get('properties') %}
        {{ dump(properties) }}
        {% if properties  %}
            {% set seoParams = seoParams|merge({ properties: app.request.get('properties') ~ seoParams }) %}
        {% endif %}
        
        {# Properly encode the SEO parameters into a string before using it #}
        {% set seoParams = '?' ~ seoParams|url_encode %}
   
        {# Check if currentNavigationId is defined and generate SEO-friendly URL #}
        {% if currentNavigationId is defined %}
            <a href="{{ seoUrl('frontend.navigation.page', { navigationId: currentNavigationId }) ~ seoParams }}"></a>
        {% endif %}
        
        {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
        
    {% endif %} 
    
    {# Call the parent pagination block #}
    {{ parent() }}
{% endblock %}
```

[image: Here I selected size L from the filter]

Could someone please help me identify what might be causing this to return null and how I can fix it? Is there anyway I can access the properties the way I am accessing the order?

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Best regards,
Lodhi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me locally without issue:

```
{% set properties = app.request.get('properties') %}
{{ dump(properties) }}
{# 01896e38492873aca93edde1c6a6b3a4|01896e38492873aca93edde1c76853fe #}
```

What didn't work was this line:

```
{% set seoParams = seoParams|merge({ properties: app.request.get('properties') ~ seoParams }) %}
```

That caused an error rendering the template. You're already merging into `seoParams` so you really don't need to concatenate them at that point, since you're URL encoding them later on. Removing the concatenation  `~ seoParams` made everything work as expected for me.